# populating a DataTable with ADO .NET entity model

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

I'm developping a windows form application with ADO .Net entity data model. I have `DataTable dt = new DataTable`, how can i populate this DataTable from the data base using dataBaseEtities?

Here is my query:

```
     from data in db.Sources 
     where data.IdTheme==idtheme 
     select data.Url;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension like this, then add it on your query:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this List<T> items)
{
    var tb = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach(var prop in props)
    {
        tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var values = new object[props.Length];
        for (var i=0; i<props.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
        }
        tb.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    return tb;
}
```

> Your query will be like this:

```
var newDataTable = (from data in db.Sources
                    where data.IdTheme == idtheme
                    select data.Url).ToDataTable();
```

Comment: also .ToDataTable() is not recognized!

Comment: you should add this extension to a static class also. I forgot to note this thing.

Comment: Check how to create an extension method for you to go on with this.